# How to maximize PopupWindowAction after popup?

Tags: prism

Can PopupWindowAction be maximized after popup? I tried to override `Invoke` method but it doesn't work

```
protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
       ...
       if (this.IsModal)
                {
                    wrapperWindow.ShowDialog();
                }
                else
                {
                    wrapperWindow.Show();
                }

    wrapperWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this class, and it worked fine for me:

```
public class MaximizedPopupWindowAction : PopupWindowAction
{
    protected override Window GetWindow( INotification notification )
    {
        var window = base.GetWindow( notification );
        window.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
        window.SourceInitialized += ( s, e ) => window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        return window;
    }
}
```